# Is it possible that jquery .html() method loads code partialy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I have a following code in jQuery:

```
$(".edit-trigger").on("click", function () {
    url = $(this).data('url');
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        $("#modal .modal-content").html(data);
    });
});
```

and it is loading following code (data) into modal window:

```
<form id="personal_info_form" class="modal-form">
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token }}" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken">
    <div class="modal-content">
        {% for field in form %}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    {{ field }}
                    <label for="{{ field.id }}" data-error="wrong">{{ field.label }}</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="modal-action modal-close">Anuluj</button>
        <button type="submit">Akceptuj</button>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
    M.updateTextFields();
</script>
```

The issue is that script in loaded code is not always executed. Is it possible to ensure execution of that script?

Comment: If you put an alert in the script, is it always shown?

Comment: No, it is not. I put alert at the begining of script and if alert shows the fields are also updated.

Comment: is the edit button visible on the DOM on page load itself?

Comment: If by edit button you mean .edit-trigger then yes, it is visible.

Comment: And to be clear, html part of loaded data always shows.

Comment: could you please create a snippet for this?